# encrypt/decrypt sensitive(mostly passwords) data in our java spring based application

Tags: java, spring, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

We are developing an application using java spring framework to manage multiple devices automatically. In the initial configuration of our application user selects the devices that needed to be managed and enters their credentials. At this time, we are saving these credentials in plain text into database. Now I needed to write an utility class to encrypt this sensitive data while saving it into DB and decrypt while retrieving them back. Basically, we don't want everyone to see these credentials by simply looking into db tables.
What is the best way to this? Sample code snippet is very helpful...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592010/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041997/what-api-and-algorithm-to-be-used-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password-using-java and lot of others

Comment: Tutorials, articles and sample code is readily available online. StackOverflow generally works best when *presenting an actual problem* (as opposed to *asking for introductory information*).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [PasswordEncoder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/core-services.html) can help you.